# Best way to pull this data

Tags: sql-server, linq, list, entity-framework-5

I have been working on an issue, where I am trying build reports based on the following data

1. List of all practice scripts were done in a time period and calculate the missed revenue on per doctor basis.

This is what I was originally doing.

1. Pulling back the list for the date range specified
2. Get the list of distinct providers from the records returned in #1
3. Traverse through each provider and get the list of scripts that were written by the provider.
4. Calculate the missed revenue, but looking at past transactions for the drug and qty that was on the script.

#1 flies through and pulls back the data quickly

#2 same for this one

#3 and #4 is where my bottle neck is happening, because for each script, I need to pull back the list of transactions for that particular drug and calculate the price per pill. And then calculate what the possible missed revenue was based on the pp (calculated) and the qty of that was on the missed script.

I am using Entity Framework for this, and an entity for scripts and a one for my past transactions. I am to the point now where I know where the bottleneck is, but I am not sure how I can get around it.

Do I go with a view and through the past transaction work into one call, or is there a way to can do this in .NET code and not having to traverse through everything one at a time on per script basis.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to answer specifically without having your table structure, but I would think using a Stored Procedure is the way to go, not a view, or iterating using EF.

1.Pulling back the list for the date range specified

Do this with a WHERE Clause in the stored procedure

2.Get the list of distinct providers from the records returned in #1

Use the DISTINCT Operator in the query

3.Traverse through each provider and get the list of scripts that were written by the provider.

Use JOIN to join to this data

4.Calculate the missed revenue, but looking at past transactions for the drug and qty that was on the script.

This can be done using a derived table or sub-select in the SP

If you can send the tables with a few sample rows I can build the SP for you.